# Can the Yamaha YDP-V240 be made to sound like the Casio AP650 with the lid open?

Tags: piano, sound

The Casio in this video (

) at around the 3 minute mark sounds amazing compared to the Yamaha YDP-V240, despite Yamaha being the better brand in general as well as being £300 more.

Is it possible to experiment with the reverb settings on the Yamaha to make it sound like the Casio I linked?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I typically prefer Casio's electric pianos over Yamaha. Casio doesn't make acoustic pianos so I can't make that comparison. I'm sure if it is a high end Yamaha you will have very good control over the reverb.

Answer (score 1):

Funny how "Celviano" could be, at a glance, so easily confused with "Clavinova".

I love the cognitive dissonance. "Yamaha is the better brand... but this Casio sounds better.."   :-)

A few points.  When you buy one, it won't sound like the demo, it never does.  "Feature" sounds can get tiring and irksome very quickly. You will never make one instrument sound EXACTLY like another (so the literal answer to your question is "no").  The room in your home where you place the instrument has a big effect on the perceived sound.